# livewire no encuentra clase de mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

cree un formulario de contacto con Livewire, el formulario funciona correctamente en localhost.
Subiendo el proyecto a producción no encuentra la clase mailable.

```
Error
Class 'App\Mail\contactoMailable' not found
```

La linea en donde no encuentra el archivo seria en app/Http/Livewire/Contact.php:74:
$correo = new contactoMailable($validatedData);

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razón en producción no encuentra el nombre de la clase.
cambiando contactoMailable a ContactoMailable se soluciono.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).